# How to send multiple files concurrently from a folder using socket programming in Python

Tags: python, sockets, concurrency, checksum

I am new to Python programming. I want to write a socket program that allows a client to send multiple files (with concurrency) from a folder to a server. For example, a client creates a folder `My Folder` with 150 files and send the files with concurrency 2, 4, and 6 from the folder to the server. That is, the client sends 2, 4, and 6 files at a time to the sever until the 150 files are sent. The application should support integrity verification where the client and the server calculate checksum of each file and compare. But now, my program only send one file from the client to the server.

client.py

```py
import hashlib
import socket
import tqdm
import os

SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 25 * 1024
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5050
filename = "file\data.xlsx"
filename = hashlib.sha3_512().hexdigest()
filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
s = socket.socket()
print(f"[+] Connecting to {host}:{port}")
s.connect((host, port))
print("[+] Connected.")
s.send(f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}".encode())
progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Sending {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        s.sendall(bytes_read)
        progress.update(len(bytes_read))
print('Successfully send the file')
s.close()
print('Connection Closed!')
```

server.py

```py
import socket
import os
import tqdm
import threading
import hashlib
SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_PORT = 5050
BUFFER_SIZE = 25 * 1024
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
s.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")
client_socket, address = s.accept()
print(f"[+] {address} is connected.")
rcv = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
filename, filesize = rcv.split(SEPARATOR)
filename = os.path.basename(filename)
filesize = int(filesize)
progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Receiving {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        f.write(bytes_read)
        progress.update(len(bytes_read))
client_socket.close()
print('File successfully received')
s.close()
print('Connection closed!')
```

Comment: Hi, how did you solved this issue? can you plz show how you did it?, Im in a similar problem when creating my server, my first idea would be to add a second separator and if that one exists start creating a new file.